# How to search for the occurrence of an attribute in any document in Marklogic database if i dont know the value of the attribute?

Tags: xquery

How do i search for an attribute present anywhere in the Marklogic database using xquery if i dont know the attribute value? i.e. I want to check if an attribute called 'court' is present in any document in my database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `exists` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-exists should help: `exists(//@court)`.